# What is the most efficient way to re-populate Choice and Lookup columns (Multiple value) in an Update Item action?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

I often find myself in this scenario:

- Create a flow with the SharePoint list `When an item is created or modified` trigger
- Add an `Update Item` action (on the same item that triggered the flow)

(For reference, I use a service account to run the flow, and a conditional structure on the `Modified By` email address to avoid an infinite loop when the flow updates the item).

Even if I want to update a *single* column value in the item, the `Update Item` action requires that you re-populate *all* column values in the item (if you leave column values blank, it will update the column values to be blank).

This is bothersome, but simple enough if the column is of type `Single Line of Text`, or even a `Choice` or `Lookup` column (Single) - the 'Dynamic Content' that is available from the original trigger can easily be added to the `Update Item` action.

However, when the column type is one of the following, it seems to become trickier:

- Choice (Multiple)
- Lookup (Multiple)

The Choice (Multiple) column [seems to require data in this format](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Update-item-with-multiple-choice-columns/m-p/426726/highlight/true#M49715):

```
[
{
  "Value": value_a
},
{
  "Value": value_b
}
]
```

And the Lookup (Multiple) column [seems to require data in this format](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/302213):

```
[
{
  "Id": 1
},
{
  "Id": 2
}
]
```

In order to get these values in the required format, I find myself having to create a loop on the original column values and manually appending each value to an array variable ([similar to the approach in this article](https://wonderlaura.com/2020/09/01/flow-update-multi-select-column/)), and then using that array variable to re-populate the same column fields.

This is VERY messy and time consuming when there are several multiple choice columns in the list.

It would be EXTREMELY HELPFUL if there was 'Dynamic Content' in the format required by the `Update Item` action.

The 'Dynamic Content' in the Power Automate interface that is available on these fields are:

```
 - ChoiceMultiple
 - ChoiceMultiple Item
 - ChoiceMultiple Value  

 - LookupMultiple  
 - LookupMultiple Item  
 - LookupMultiple Value 
 - LookupMultiple Id
```

But I don't know what these different values refer to (and they often get put in a loop when I try and use them - even if I am putting them in a field in 'array input mode').

Am I overlooking something?

Is there a way to repopulate multiple value fields without having to manually construct an array of objects in the format required in the `Update Item` action?

In order to troubleshoot the issue, I did a `Compose` on the `body` value that is grabbed via the trigger action:

Choice column (Multiple) data looks like this:

```
"ChoiceMultiple": [
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
    "Id": 0,
    "Value": "Choice A"
  },
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
    "Id": 1,
    "Value": "Choice B"
  }
],

"ChoiceMultiple@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference)",

"ChoiceMultiple#Id": [
  0,
  1
],

"ChoiceMultiple#Id@odata.type": "#Collection(Int64)"
```

Lookup column (Multiple) data look like this:

```
"LookupMultiple": [
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
    "Id": 1,
    "Value": "Value A"
  },
  {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
    "Id": 2,
    "Value": "Value B"
  }
],

"LookupMultiple@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference)",

"LookupMultiple#Id": [
  1,
  2
],

"LookupMultiple#Id@odata.type": "#Collection(Int64)"
```

Comment: Are these required/mandatory fields in list? What happens if those are not mandatory and you do not pass the value for these columns in update item action?

Comment: Also, instead of using "Apply to each" action, you can use "Select" action to generate values in specific/required format.

Comment: Can I infer from the first comment that only Required fields need to be passed a value?  And that fields that are not Required do not need a value specified (and retain their existing value)?  And in regards to the second comment, a multiple Choice column has three Dynamic Content values available:  `ChoiceMultipleColumn`, `ChoiceMultipleColumn Item` and `ChoiceMultipleColumn Value`.  I used `ChoiceMultipleColumn` as the `From` value in the `Select` and `ChoiceMultipleColumn Value` as the mapped value and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Yes, if fields are not required, you don't need to pass the value again in update item action. That's how it worked in the past. You can try it once from your side to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this suggestions for your requirements:

A. Instead of using "Apply to each" action to get the lookup and choice column values in required format, you can use **Select** action to generate values in specific/required format very easily. It also reduces the number actions / API calls in your power automate flow

B. If you lookup and choice fields are not required/mandatory in SharePoint list, you don't need to pass the value to these columns again in update item action. Try using update item action without passing any value in these non mandatory fields.

Comment: Confirming that `Select` works well to 'reshape' the objects in an array of objects and that when using the `Update Item` action, you DO NOT need to repopulate fields with the same values submitted, UNLESS they are Required fields, in which case you cannot Save the flow unless a value is provided.